# How can I design with the MF52B2 104F3950 thermistor?

Tags: temperature, thermistor

I need to design a circuit that maintains a temperature, using [this](https://www.tme.eu/Document/f9d2f5e38227fc1c7d979e546ff51768/NTCM-100K-B3950.pdf) thermistor. Does anyone have general math that works for any thermistor that I can use to create a circuit with it?

I would not like to use a microcontroller of any kind.

Comment: What temperature do you need to regulate to? Is this temperature always the same? If the temperature is programmable by the user, what is the user input? What is the tolerance? The answer to these questions can determine if a simple on/off control is sufficient, or if you need a more complicated control loop.

Comment: @Mattman944 I just need an on-off switch. It is always heating to exactly 90°C from ambient. I'm heating with a pcb heater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use a simple on/off controller using a comparator. R4 would be set to be equal to the thermistor resistance at the desired set point, about 8.8k. R1 provides some hysteresis/deadband, without it, the circuit could oscillate at a high frequency near the set point and stress the transistor.

This is just a starting point. You haven't given enough information for a final design.

If you want math, these are just voltage dividers. Make an Excel spreadheet that calculates the comparator input voltages, that is what I would do. Note that there are two thresholds because of the hysteresis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw9NPC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit: I built the circuit, mostly so it can be used as a building block so I can expand it and convert it to a PID controller.

I lowered the set point to about 58 degC. I don't want to burn myself.

You can't accurately measure the voltage from the scope plot, but the system is so slow that you can measure it with a meter. Here I converted the voltages to temperature.

The rising threshold is 58.6 °C.
The falling threshold is 56.2 °C.
It overshoots to 59.0 °C.
It undershoots to 56.8 °C.
The regulation is 59.0 - 56.8 = 2.2 °C.

I have a large thermal mass, the thermal lag is high. Your overshoot and undershoot may be less. Or, it could be more, I don't know your system.

I have about 0.4 °C of hysteresis. This is equivalent to 18 mV in my system. The noise in the circuit should be significantly less than this, or the circuit won't behave well. This isn't that hard to achieve, but an inexperienced person could easily have a lot more noise than this in their circuit.

If you use the same power for the comparator as you do for the heater, the MOSFET switching noise can easily affect the thermistor circuit if you aren't careful. Using a separate regulator helps a lot.

The comparator is a basic cheap part. Your accuracy specification may require a better part.

The NTC thermistor is the component above the resistor in the picture.

[image]

[image]

[image]